# Haskell; Parse error on input 'module'

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a parser in Haskell, and am having trouble with it compiling. The error is "parse error on input 'module'. I can fix this error by taking away the brackets, but then the error just switches to "parse error on input "%". I have also tried removing the `module Main where` line, but that still give me the error on input for "%".

```
{
module Main where
}

%name parser
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token
...
```

Comment: What is the exact sequence of commands you are running?

Comment: @DanielWagner I am using the command `:l Main.hs`

Comment: This is a happy grammar - it should have a `.y` suffix and you need to compile it with `happy` before loading it into GHCi. Note that if this is part of a larger project, Cabal can handle that second part for you (just make sure to include `happy` in `build-tools`).

Comment: Okay. This is not Haskell code, and cannot be used directly by ghc(i). Presumably you got this code from a tutorial or similar; you should consult the tutorial to know for sure the right way to build this code. It needs to be preprocessed by some tool (probably alex or happy?) to produce Haskell code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is not a Haskell file. It looks like it is a grammar file for a parser generator, (likely [Happy](https://www.haskell.org/happy/)).

You should first rename your grammar file to use the `.y` file extension, since it is a grammar file and isn't a Haskell source code file. Then, invoke the parser generator to generate the `Main.hs` from the `Main.y` you have

```
happy Main.y
```

Finally, you can take this generated `Main.hs` file and run it with ghc.